# Converting Character cells in an integer column to NA, in read.csv

Tags: r

I have a csv where i am defining the classes while importing. Some of the columns are integer classes. The problem i have is that if some user writes "three" instead of "3" in one of those columns the whole function stops working.

What i would want him to do, is to convert any text into NA's while importing. I have seen that you can use na.strings = ..., but that would apply to all columns, right? I only want to exclude characters from one column, not from the whole csv.

Is there an easy solution to this, or do i have to manually check each column for such values and convert them to NA's?

EDIT: Additional information:
this is what my code looks like:

```
df <- read.csv(text=capture.output(write.csv(d.xxx,row.names=FALSE)), 
                  colClasses=d.yyy,
                  header = TRUE)
```

where

```
d.xxx is a data frame containing the values and
d.yyy is a list containing "integer","character",etc. in the correct order
```

EDIT2: This is the error i get:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'a real', got '"2"'
```

Comment: You can specify the `colClasses= c('integer', 'character')` etc in `read.csv` if there are columns with mixed class.  So, if there are 'three' in a an integer column  specified in `colClasses`, it would be converted to NA

Comment: Can you change the column types after importing with `as.numeric()` ? It will produce NAs when you have characters.

Comment: @akrun thats what i did and waht i expected would happen. Instead it doesn't import the file and says `Expected a real, got "2"`

Comment: @Hugo the problem i have is that it stops the import, therefore not letting me alter the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just import the column as strings and then run `as.numeric()` on the column in the data.frame. That will return a vector of numeric values for actual numbers and NAs for elements that are strings.

Comment: This could be a workaround, but it will complicate things, as the list "integer","character",etc is user-generated and therfore using read.csv() was very helpful, as it allowed me to just simply refer to this list.

But i guess if there is no other way i will have to use as.numeric()...